# query finding non associated records based on a user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

For the user_id in friendships the friend_id would be the "other" user and I want to select all users where a friendship doesn't exist yet.

I am using Ruby on Rails and I've tried to write this in one query with rails syntax but having difficulty I've gone for a raw SQL which is exactly what I need but it gives me back no results.

```
 SELECT u.id, u.name, u.avatar_url FROM users u LEFT JOIN friendships f on f.friend_id=u.id WHERE f.friend_id IS NULL AND f.user_id = ? ORDER BY u.updated_at DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: try `User.includes(:friendships).where(friendships: { id: nil })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've got this working nicely with table indexes on all keys but I'd rather have a rails way of doing it than pure SQL.

```
User.find_by_sql(["SELECT id, avatar_url, name FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM friendships WHERE friend_id=?) ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 9", session[:ytuserid]]).to_a
```

The current user can now see 9 people where the friendship doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.avatar_url
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN friendships f on f.friend_id = u.id
WHERE f.friend_id IS NULL
ORDER BY u.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Get rid of `AND f.user_id = ?`.  The above query is going to find all users with no friends, I'm not sure what the purpose of the additional `AND` was for, but it seems like why you're not getting any results back.